# Как правильно дождаться завершения задачи?

Tags: c#, tpl

Помогите разобраться, есть такой код:

```
foreach (var advert in rtb_partners)
        {
            if (advert == null)
                throw new Exception("Dsp not found");

            var protocol = advert.Protocol;
            if (protocol != RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_2 &&
                protocol != RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_3 &&
                protocol != RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_4 &&
                protocol != RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_5)
                throw new Exception("RTB protocol not supported");

            bids[i] = ProcessBidRequest(bidRequest, advert.Endpoint, protocol);
            i++;
        }
```

Тут все стандартно, внутри foreach вызывается метод ProcessBidRequest(), вот его код

```
public async Task<AuctionRequest> ProcessBidRequest(BidRequestModel requestModel, string endpoint, RtbProtocolEnum protocol)
    {
        try
        {
            var requestString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestModel);
            string address = @"http://192.168.56.1:8000/response.json";
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, address);
            request.Content = new StringContent(requestString);
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            switch (protocol)
            {
                case RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_2:
                    request.Headers.Add("x-openrtb-version", "2.2");
                    break;
                case RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_3:
                    request.Headers.Add("x-openrtb-version", "2.3");
                    break;
                case RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_4:
                    request.Headers.Add("x-openrtb-version", "2.4");
                    break;
                case RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_5:
                    request.Headers.Add("x-openrtb-version", "2.5");
                    break;
            }
             using (var response = await _client.SendAsync(request))
            {
                var respString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NoContent && response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    throw new BadResponseException(response.ReasonPhrase);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(respString))
                    throw new ArgumentException("The value is null.");

                return new AuctionRequest(requestModel, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BidResponseModel>(respString), protocol);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning(ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Когда debug доходит до этой строки "using (var response = await _client.SendAsync(request))", то выполнение возвращается обратно в цикл foreach и получается, что я не могу прочитать содержимое первой итерации, можно это как нибудь исправить?

P.S. Вторая итерация проходит нормально и результат удается прочитать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, неплохо бы причесать код асинхронного метода

```cs
public async Task<AuctionRequest> ProcessBidRequest(BidRequestModel requestModel, string endpoint, RtbProtocolEnum protocol)
{
    try
    {
        string protocolVersion = protocol switch
        {
            RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_2 => "2.2",
            RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_3 => "2.3",
            RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_4 => "2.4",
            RtbProtocolEnum.OpenRTB_2_5 => "2.5",
            _ => throw new NotSupportedException("RTB protocol not supported")
        };

        var requestString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestModel);
        string address = @"http://192.168.56.1:8000/response.json";
        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, address)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(requestString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        };
        request.Headers.Add("x-openrtb-version", protocolVersion);

        using var response = await _client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
 
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new BadResponseException(response.ReasonPhrase);
        // можно еще так без условия response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var respString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (respString.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("The response is empty string.");

        return new AuctionRequest(requestModel, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BidResponseModel>(respString), protocol);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning(ex.Message);
        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex).Throw(); // сохранить оригинальный Stack Trace
        throw;
    }
}
```

Во-вторых, чтобы дождаться асинхронную операцию, надо использовать `await`

```cs
foreach (var advert in rtb_partners)
{
    if (advert == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(advert), "Dsp not found");

    bids[i++] = await ProcessBidRequest(bidRequest, advert.Endpoint, advert.Protocol);
}
```

Если хочется распараллелить асинхронные операции, то можно так:

```cs
List<Task<AuctionRequest>> tasks = new List<Task<AuctionRequest>>();
foreach (var advert in rtb_partners)
{
    if (advert == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(advert), "Dsp not found");

    tasks.Add(ProcessBidRequest(bidRequest, advert.Endpoint, advert.Protocol));
}
AuctionRequest[] bids = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```