# Как отправить несколько параллельно выполняющихся Http запросов?

Tags: c#

Помогите разобраться, необходимо в программе на C# отправить сразу несколько Http-запросов при этом их выполнение должно идти параллельно, у меня есть следующий алгоритм:

1 Взять коллекцию адресов с которыми будем работать

```
ICollection<RtbModel> rtb_partners; // Адреса в интернете
```

2 Создать массив Task(ов), который будет сохранять полученные ответы

```
var bids = new Task<AuctionRequest>[rtb_partners.Count];
```

3 В цикле `foreach` начать перебор массива адресов с дальнешйшим выполнением запроса

```
 foreach (var advert in rtb_partners)
{
 await (bids[i++] = ProcessBidRequest(advert));
} 

public async Task<AuctionRequest> ProcessBidRequest(string adress)
{
  try
     {
      string address = adress;

      using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, address);
      {
        using var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
        var respString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      }
}
```

Как правильно написать метод `ProcessBidRequest()`, чтобы запрос отправлялись параллельно и на выходе были только ответы с успешным выполнением?

Comment: Я на c#/dotnet бекенд не писал, но, возможно, вам необходимо применять программный брокер RabbitMQ для трудоемких и  асинхронных  запросов.  Надеюсь, эти статьи вам помогут: 1)  https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/rabbitmq-event-bus-development-test-environment  2) https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1293350/373567 я же вам в ответе на прошлый вопрос написал, как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет [Task.WhenAll](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7.2), это аналог Promise.All JS, или CompositeFuture.All в java

Создаете таск для списока тасков и выставляете хендлер на обработку ответов по завершении всех.

пример из ссылки

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      int failed = 0;
      var tasks = new List<Task>();
      String[] urls = { "www.adatum.com", "www.cohovineyard.com",
                        "www.cohowinery.com", "www.northwindtraders.com",
                        "www.contoso.com" };
      
      foreach (var value in urls) {
         var url = value;
         tasks.Add(Task.Run( () => { var png = new Ping();
                                     try {
                                        var reply = png.Send(url);
                                        if (! (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)) {
                                           Interlocked.Increment(ref failed);
                                           throw new TimeoutException("Unable to reach " + url + ".");
                                        }
                                     }
                                     catch (PingException) {
                                        Interlocked.Increment(ref failed);
                                        throw;
                                     }
                                   }));
      }
      Task t = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
      try {
         t.Wait();
      }
      catch {}   

      if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
         Console.WriteLine("All ping attempts succeeded.");
      else if (t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
         Console.WriteLine("{0} ping attempts failed", failed);      
   }
}
// The example displays output like the following:
//       5 ping attempts failed
```